# CMake Error - not able to open an input file?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am getting this error

```
fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '.\cm_project.dir\SharedCRT-Release\dummy.obj'
```

when I compile a program through CMake. dummy.cpp is a source file within my project...

Any ideas?

This is my CmakeLists.txt file:

```
project( cm_project )

set(SOURCES 
  src/dummy.cpp
  include/version.h
)

add_library( cm_project STATIC ${SOURCES} )

set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH
  $(PlatformName)
)
```

Comment: Please post relevant parts of your CMakeFiles.txt files, I'm afraid it is not possible to guess what might go wrong right now.

Comment: is there an dummy.obj file at the location specified? Do you have read privileges on it?

Comment: @SirDarius: Sure, I have posted that.

Comment: What is the generator you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

First check to see if the file actually exists. If it doesn't, try to find the reason for this (e.g. some compile error before). There might as well be file permission issues (some process got stuck) or anything else. Also check the name of your build dir, it should be an absolute path, because `.` is relative and might change depending on your current working directory.

Comment: Well, the thing is, I have a working version of this project in Visual Studio, and I was trying to get it to compile through CMake.